# How this change of variable works?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable

Let $d, r, \alpha >0$, $j\ge 1$, $t_j\in\mathbb{R}$, $N\ge 2$ be a natural number with conjugate $N^{\prime}$ and $\omega_{N-1}$ the area of the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^N$.
I am trying to justify the equality
$$\int_{d/j}^d e^{\alpha t_j^{N^{\prime}}[\log(d/r)]^{N^{\prime}}/(\omega_{N-1}\log j)^{1/(N-1)}} r^{N-1} dr =d^N \log j\int_0^1 e^{-Nt[1-(t_j/t_0)^{N^{\prime}}t^{1/(N-1)}]\log j} dt, $$
where $t=\log(d/r)/ \log j$ and $t_0^{N^{\prime}}=[N\omega_{N-1}^{1/(N-1)}]/\alpha$.

Actually I do not understand how it is made the change of variables and how to change the extrema of integration. Could someone please help me to understand that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What exactly is unclear? Putting the limits of the r integral into the formula gives the limits for the t integral. Seems pretty routine. Ugly but straightforward.

Comment: @daw, I tried but I don't find the result in RHS. I am ok with extrema, but not for the same exponential on RHS.